# How to start a specific instance, when another instance is overloaded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 instances, connected to a load balancer. I would like to stop 1 instance, and start it only when a certain alarm happens, for example when the first intance has a high CPU load.

I couldn't find how to do it. in the Auto scaling group, i see i can launch a brand new instance, but that's not what i want, i want a specific instance to start.

I couldn't find how to connect an alert to an action - wake up this specific instance.

Should this be done in the load balancer configuration? i couldn't find how...

Comment: There is no automatic service to stop/start an instance based on load. It is highly recommended that you use Auto Scaling, since it can also replace failed instances and can launch new instances in a different Availability Zone in case an AZ fails. It also integrates with ELB to register new instances and removed terminated instances. By only having two instances that you stop/start, you are still thinking in the old-fashioned 'on-premises' way rather than taking advantage of full cloud capabilities. Rather than putting effort into automating start/stop, try using Auto Scaling.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the way autoscaling is supposed to work, and hence the solution to your particular problem is a little bit more complex than simply using autoscaling to create new instances in response to metric thresholds being crossed. It may be worth asking yourself exactly why you need to do it this way and whether it could be achieved in the usual way.

In order to achieve starting (and stopping) a particular instance you'll need three pieces:

- A CloudWatch Alarm triggered by the metric you need (`CPUUtilization`) crossing your desired threshold.
- An SNS topic that is triggered by the alarm in the previous step.
- A lambda function (with the correct IAM permissions) that is subscribed to the SNS topic, which sends the relevant API calls to EC2 to start or stop the instances when the notification from SNS arrives. You can find some examples of the code needed to do this eg [here in node.js](https://github.com/marcelog/aws-lambda-start-stop-instances/blob/master/index.js) and [here from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/) although there are probably others if you prefer another language.

Once you put all these together you should be able to respond to a change in CPU with starting and stopping particular instances.